# Haystack with Elasticsearch refuses to create search index

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Django (master branch) and Haystack (master branch) connected to an Elasticsearch server. The Python version is 3.4.

The search index class looks like this:

```
class PageIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = fields.EdgeNgramField(document=True)
    name = fields.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name', boost=2)
    tags = fields.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='tags', boost=1.5)
    description = fields.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='description_summary', boost=0.9)

    def get_model(self):
        return Page

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(created__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

When I try to create the index, I get the following error:

```
> python manage.py update_index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Indexing 7 communities
PUT /haystack [status:400 request:0.013s]
ERROR:root:Error updating page using default 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 221, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 266, in update_backend
    do_update(backend, index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 89, in do_update
    backend.update(index, current_qs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 158, in update
    prepped_data = index.full_prepare(obj)
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 204, in full_prepare
    self.prepared_data = self.prepare(obj)
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/indexes.py", line 187, in prepare
    ID: get_identifier(obj),
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/utils/__init__.py", line 33, in default_get_identifier
    obj_or_string._meta.module_name,
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'module_name'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receiving this error message because in Django >= 1.6 Options.module_name changed to .model_name (this is widley abused non-public API) so you just need change in haystack code module_name

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that you have an attribute named "**name**" in your models.

**models.py**

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**search_index.py**

```
class PageIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    name = fields.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name', boost=2)
```